# Histogram of grouped data outputting equal frequencies

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = {'Age Group': ['0-9', '10-24', '25-44', '45-64', '65+'], 'count': [66, 93, 143, 133, 122]}
```

[image]

I want to create a histogram showing the distribution of age groups using matplotlib:

```
plt.hist(male['count'], density=True, bins=30)  # density=False would make counts
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Age Group');
```

[image]

Why are all the frequency values here equal? I can't seem to figure out how to plot this correctly, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common misconception. A histogram (hist) requires a raw (i.e. non aggregated) dataset to plot (there is effectively only **one** row for each group in your dataset).

Here you already have aggregates so you need a **barplot**.

```
plt.bar(df['Age Group'], df['count'])
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`plt.hist(male['count'], ...)` plots the histogram of `male['count']`, which is the array/list `[66, 93, 143, 133, 122]`. Each number appears there exactly once, so the histogram shows a uniform distribution.